# Azure Data Factory (ADF): Failed to run Pipeline Bad Request

Tags: bad-request, azure-data-factory

I have a simple master pipeline that executes multiple other pipelines in parallel. When I trigger the individual child pipelines manually, I have no issue. But when I try to run the master pipeline it returns a BadRequest, with an empty message.

````
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/a15ff459-a32e-4127-8b57-20695d2b1979",
"details": null,
"error": null
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the name of one of the Pipeline execution tasks/blocks has a trailing whitespace, once this was removed the master pipeline was able to run successfully.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! I just tidied up some of my activity names, and you've saved me a whole load of invisible pain...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but in my case was related to a missing comma at `@concat()` dynamic expression.

It wasn't a good troubleshoot since ADF doesn't alert about it at any time.

Regards,
Ogata